# Why is df.head() not working in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi there everyone I am working on a project with python which needs data frames so I am using pandas but there seem to be a problem to when ever I go and type in `print(data.head())` `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'`
below is the rest of my code any help will be awesome.

```
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = quandl.get_table('WIKI/PRICES')
print(data.head())
```

Comment: What is `type(data)`? probably not a dataframe, looks like a list. print data and check for contents.

Comment: I suppose that you need to convert data into df: data = pd.DataFrame(data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the list to a pandas DataFrame first. After that you will be able to do `data.head()`. Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```